# How can I override Storybook story's max width?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

The storybook library has max-width:1000px for story wrapper. How can I avoid that maximum for only 1 story?

I am building a story that should be half of the screen and that's why I need to expand wrapper for example to have 50vw.

Story example:

```
import { Meta, StoryObj } from "@storybook/react";
import MyComponent from "./components/MyComponent ";

const meta: Meta = {
  title: "MyComponent",
  component: MyComponent,
  decorators: [
    (Story) => (
      <div>
        <Story />
      </div>
    ),
  ],
};

export default meta;
```

I already tried to set width for  wrapper but it's not working since storybook has own wrapper with max-width: 1000px;

Comment: You should be able to put a class on the wrapper and apply CSS to the appropriate element inside the component using a descendant selector.

Comment: You could set `parameters: {layout: 'fullscreen'}` on a particular story.